# split very large text into documents by matching regex in python

Tags: python, regex

i have a very large file (~4 GB) which look like this:

```
<P ID=000ajevz>
OBJECTIVE: Fludarabine, cyclophosphamide and rituximab (FCR) therapy for lymphoid malignancies has historically been associated with a low reported incidence of Pneumocystis jirovecii pneumonia (PJP). However, prophylaxis was routinely used in early studies,.............................
</P>
<P ID=000q5l5n>
SIMPLE SUMMARY: The role of rodents in the transmission of many diseases is widely known. Wild rats abundant in urban environments may transmit diseases to humans and other animals, including laboratory rodents used for biomedical research in research facilities,......
</P>
```

I am trying to read the whole file at once and then split it using regex: `'<P ID=(\w+)>(.*?)</P>'`

to process the text of my file onto a posting list to apply tfidf.

My code looks like:

```
import time
import re
import json
import string
import numpy as np
import collections
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


filename = 'corpus3.txt'
text = open(filename, encoding ='utf8').read() #read all text of file at once

doc = re.finditer(r'<P ID=(\w+)>(.*?)</P>', text, re.S) #split text into documents by matching regular expression
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english')) #load stopwords from nltk

no_docs = 0 #number of processed documents
doc_freq = Counter() #document frequency of each term
col _freq = Counter() #collection frequency

doc_id = 0
id_dict = dict()

data = collections.defaultdict(list) #dictionary of key:word and values:(docid, termfrequency)
for (docid, text) in [(x.group(1), x.group(2)) for x in doc]:
    no_docs += 1
    text = text.lower()
    #wordcount = Counter(text.split())
    wordcount = Counter(re.split(r'\W+', text))
    #wordcount = Counter(word[:5] for word in text.split()) #5-stemming
    doc_id +=1
    id_dict[doc_id] = docid
    for (word, count) in wordcount.items():
        if word.isalpha():
            if not word in STOPWORDS:
                #word_stem = word[:5]
                doc_freq[word] += 1
                col_freq[word] += count
                data[word].append((doc_id, count))

flattend = (item for tag in data.values() for item in tag) #[(docid, tf)]
posting = (item  for tag in flattend for item in tag ) #[docid, tf]
posting_list = list(posting)
```

But i keep getting memory error when it tries to read the whole file at once. I tried in google colab, my colab crashes out of memory. 
I tried to slice my file and read only 1/4 of my file, it gives my memoryerror.
I also tried to read it line by line, but then i dont know how to iterate through those lines and split using regex to get a single iterator to process later.

Comment: Is the regex you are looking for always on the single line? Is it possible that it is split by two lines?

Comment: Well, I am trying to split my file into documents like this:
<P ID=000ajevz>
OBJECTIVE: Fludarabine, cyclophosphamide and rituximab (FCR) therapy for lymphoid malignancies has historically been associated with a low reported incidence of Pneumocystis jirovecii pneumonia (PJP). However, prophylaxis was routinely used in early studies,.............................
</P>
So, I am looking for regex: '<P ID=(\w+)>(.*?)</P>' to split the document inside <P ID=(\w+)> until </P>

Comment: The first part of the regex: <P ID=' '> is always on a single line and the last part of the regex: </P> is also always on a single line.

Comment: precisely which line do you get a memory error at, the `.read()`?

Comment: Yes. I get memory error at .read()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a generator like this

```py
def read_until(f, close_tag):
    line = f.readline()
    while not line.startswith(close_tag):
        yield line
        line = f.readline()

def get_docid(line):
    id_start = line.find("ID=") + 3
    id_end = line.find(">")
    return line[id_start:id_end]

def read_doc(f):
    """Split text into documents"""
    text = ""
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        if line.startswith("<P"):
            docid = get_docid(line)
            # read until closing tag
            for rest_line in read_until(f, "</P"):
                text += rest_line
            yield (docid, text)
            text = ""
        line = f.readline()
```

This lets you read line by line and still split it the way you want. It works because the `<P>` tags are always on their own lines. You can replace the for loop in your code with

```py
docfile = open(filename)
for docid, text in read_doc(docfile):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and comment again to let you know if it works.